# ElasticSearch - Aggregations: filtering and sorting buckets

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Using ElasticSearch 5.2

As an example I'll be using a database representing all people in the world.

Example request: Get the average salary of a person, grouped by country, for everyone older than 30 years old. (Response should contain the top 10 countries with their average salary)

Steps i took to build my aggregation query:

1. Filter the raw dataset (`filter: age > 30`)
2. Aggregate on '`country`'
3. Use metric Avg on field '`salary`'

The problem that I'm facing is that I can either apply a filter before aggregating, or sort the buckets, but it seems like ES does not allow me to do both?
In other words: I cannot apply my "`order`" query on "`myInnerAggregation`" because it's preceded by "`myFilterAggregation`"

```
GET myIndex/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
  "myAggregation": {
  "terms": {
    "size":10,
    "field": "country",
    "order": [
      {
        "myInnerAggregation": "desc"
          // I cannot specify "myInnerAggregation" here, only 
          // "myFilterAggregation" (because it's out of scope I guess)
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggs": {
    "myFilterAggregation": {
      "filter": { /* age > 30 (filter syntax is not the problem)*/},
      "aggs": {
        "myInnerAggergation": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "salary"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

I've seen that ES 6.1+ has support for "`bucket_sort`", which would probably solve this problem, but I cannot believe a simple aggregation like this cannot be handled by ES 5.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
"order": [
      {
        "MyFilterAggregation>MyInnerAggregation": "desc"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the filter to the [`query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/search-request-query.html) part of the request. You don't have to declare your filter as an aggregation, aggregations respect filters defined in the `query` part of your request. Hopefully this way you can get around your issue.